# Alignment of tabs on profile page in MathOverflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This morning, on several machines, with Windows 8.1, XP, and CentOS, and with Chrome and Firefox, on MathOverflow, the profile page shows:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm this. I'm using Firefox on Mac OS X.

Comment: Hasn't it been like this for a while? Anyway, it's the same on Chrome for OSX. I get the same misalignment on Safari on my iPhone too.

Comment: @YuichiroFujiwara: The Wayback Machine has profile captures from October. But the results are confusing. For example, for the same user on two dates, Oct 10th and Oct 31st, the earlier one is bad and the later one is good: http://web.archive.org/web/20131010103920/http://mathoverflow.net/users/9072/quid and http://web.archive.org/web/20131031073637/http://mathoverflow.net/users/9072/quid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have pushed a fix for this visual bug. The fix will go on live server within 24 hours after our production build.

Comment: It seems that tabs in profiles are back to their correct position, however, tabs on answers are too high for a change now (you can see it at this very page).

Comment: This seems now fixed, too. The remaining nitpick is something I normally wouldn’t even notice, and it seems browser-dependent (I can see it in Firefox, but it displays correctly in Opera): the tabs appear horizontally misaligned by one pixel with the horizontal lines. This manifests as a white spot at the lower right corners of unselected tabs, and (even harder to notice) at the lower left corner of the selected tab.

Comment: Hmm. And in a (rather old version of) Konqueror, there are white spots at both corners of unselected tabs, whereas the selected tab is all right.

Comment: Oh. In Chrome, there are tringular-shaped glitches at both corners. So it’s probably not a misalignment after all, but browser-dependent implementation of the junction of two differently coloured borders.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: The missing pixel in one or both corners of the tab, and the Chrome issue, was reported two days ago in http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210712/147362, with "status-declined".

Comment: I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @jzy: Thank you for all the effort you are putting in these matters.