# Tabs misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The horizontal line on tabs on the profile page is misaligned:

[image: screenshot]

[image: another screenshot]

This happens both on the main site, and on meta. The screenshots above are from Firefox 14 on Linux, however, I verified the problem also affects Chrome 49 on Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Does Firefox 14 still exist (this must be quite old)? -- I think the recent version is 46.0. -- Anyway I can reproduce the bug also in Firefox 46.0.

Comment: Yes, it exists, and despite that the browser world has gone bananas with version numbers going through the roof, less than four years is NOT old. But yes, I also checked it in a more recent browser as I wrote, it’s just that the logistics of generating screenshots on my tablet is more complicated than on my (arguably old) desktop.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1252/alignment-of-tabs-on-profile-page-in-mathoverflow.

Comment: @jeq Eh -- Kind of similar, but for a different reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for sharing this issue. I also noticed the issue today and pushed a fix which is now live on production. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: All right, thank you.